# How to refresh an iframe in a page made with Espasyncwebserver

Tags: esp8266

So, I have this page on esp8266:

```cpp
  controlserver.on("/UDEL", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/html", htmltd);
  });
```

`htmltd`  is a string, generated by a function and it contains some forms, and they run in iframe tag,

```html
<FORM action="/process" method="post" id="config" target="iframe">


</form>

<iframe style="visibility: hidden;" src="http://" )+local_IPstr+"/UDEL"  name="iframe"></iframe>
```

and processed by:

```cpp
controlserver.on("/process", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
.
.
.
request->send(200, "text/html", HTML_CSS_STYLING + "<script>alert(\" Deleted \")</script>");
.
.
.
});
```

They work perfectly fine, and after clicking on submit button the page shows an alert, and it must be reloaded, because the submitted form must be removed from the page. it happens when I reload the page manually. but I want it to happen automatically after each form submission. it tried many ways like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Reload iFrame</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" id="myIframe"></iframe>

   
  <input onclick="reloadIframe()"  type="button" value="Click me">

    <script>
      function reloadIframe() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
        iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't work in esp8266.

Comment: `it doesn't work` ... that is an extremely vague description of an observed behavior .... what exactly happens? ... please update your question ... **do not** add information in comments

Comment: `form must be removed from the page` ... why don't you simply hide it? ... page reload would not be necessary

Comment: here is an example of updating a web page without a reload
 https://projecthub.arduino.cc/donskytech/nodemcu-esp8266-ajax-enabled-web-server-928fa0

Comment: @jsotola yeah you are right, I was working on this all day, I was a little tired. nothing happens when I tried the described method. My project is kind of big and there are many forms in this page, so I wanted to save some space. thank you, I'll look, into it.

Comment: your main page could be just skeleton html that uses XHR to load each form as needed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, your intention is to automatically reload the main page (which contains the form and the iframe) after submitting the form. but the challenge is that the form submits inside the iframe so when you send a response to the iframe, it won't directly impact the main page.

I believe you could use a small trick to work this problem around.

1- After successfully processing the form data inside the iframe, send back a script that communicates with the parent window (the main page) and instructs it to reload

2- In the main page, listen to the received message and then reload.

Here is how to implement the proposed solution:

On your ESP8266 route handler, send a script in the response to post a message to the parent window after processing the form:

```python
controlserver.on("/process", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    //add your processing code
    String response = HTML_CSS_STYLING + 
                      "<script>" 
                      "window.parent.postMessage('reloadPage', '*');" 
                      "</script>";
    request->send(200, "text/html", response);
});
```

window.parent.postMessage will send "reloadPage" string from iframe to parent window. And on your main page (the page that contains the iframe), listen for this message and reload the entire page when the message is received:

```
<FORM action="/process" method="post" id="config" target="iframe">
    <!-- form field here -->
</form>

<iframe style="visibility: hidden;" src="http://"+local_IPstr+"/UDEL" name="iframe"></iframe>

<script>
    // listen for messages from iframes
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        // Await reloadPage message
        if(event.data === 'reloadPage') {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Btw instead of using an iframe, you could use AJAX to submit the form so that you get a response directly from the server and refresh the page using `location.reload()`. This way you can submit form data (or retrieve data) without refreshing the entire page. Only the necessary parts of the page updates.

I hope that this helps, if not, please inform me.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much it worked like a charm! I know nothing about the AJAX :) Basically I started html like 2 weeks ago ;)

Comment: I am glad to hear that it worked for u, AJAX is used for asynchronous web applications but don't rush it. You will eventually learn about it. Have a nice day, coding!